# Android - boolean JSON deserialization always return false (int format)

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, deserialization

When deserializing a JSON to a custom bean (doesn't matter what bean is, even with one boolean field) the boolean value red from a sqlite table is not properly processed.

In according with the sqlite rules, in the JSON the boolean value is shown as an integer value (0 for false, true otherwise).

When calling the fromJson method with the right parameters, the boolean is always deserialized as false, even when JSON value is 1.

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5977499/1768336) and the relative [extern link](http://hussainpithawala.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/overriding-default-serializationdeserialization-behaviour-of-jackson-json-serializer/). Sincerely i have not tested it, due to it's complicated implementation (don't know if it really matches my problem).

I'm looking for a lighter solution for doing that.

Thank you,
L.F.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace true and false by strings "y" and "n" and serialize that; after deserialization, you'd need a reversal conversion. This probably is equivalent to the mentioned solution, but requires less reuse of other people's code.

Another option is to use int-s instead of boolean-s in your data structures.

Comment: I tried the second solution, deserializing as Integer and using the getter like as follow:

    public boolean getTextboxvisible()
    {
        return this.textBoxVisible != 0;
    }


but with this solution I have to edit all the pojo class on the solution...

I would like to setup a generic custom deserializer that extends the base deserializer with the "Int to boolean" check. Is it possible ?